# how to put dialog box inside the page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to put this dialog box inside the page refresh. i mean. when i refresh the page this must be the out put.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {
                "I want to Continue the Exam": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "I Refresh": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to show this dialog when a user presses the refresh button (or F5) in the browser?

Comment: yea your right dude!

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Your only option is to use [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload)

Comment: thank you. . sorry for newbie favor. can u use that onbeforeunload. using my dialog box. . put the code here please.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers have a security feature that will not let a page prevent users from leaving the page. By leaving a page it means closing tab/browser, navigating to a different page or refreshing. The only way to stop the user is to assign a function to `onbeforeunload`. Like this:

```
onbeforeunload = function () { return "You have unsaved data. Are you sure you want to exit?"; }
```

This message is synchronous, it will stop all javascript running on the page. If user presses ok the browser will leave the page (or refresh) else it will stay on the page.

**EDIT**

*Usage*: when user have changed something and have unsaved data - you assign a function to `onbeforeunload`:

```
onbeforeunload = function () { return "some message"; }
```

after the data is saved set `onbeforeunload` to null:

```
onbeforeunload = null;
```

Comment: how do i apply this code sir? 
when i use this on my netbeans they mark it read.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, when you 'refresh' a page then all the JS objects are destroyed (those that are written in script).In other words the script is re-loaded. So you can't persist your script while the page is in transition.

Type I (classical Single Page App)- 
So if you simply want to reload a particular part of the Application then use $.ajax() methods like beforeSend() for showing whatever (alert or best a loading spinner/div) you want during the data request or 'page-refresh'. And then you can hide them on done().

Type II (using routers)
JS frameworks like Angular give you options to reload a particular route of your App without reloading/refreshing your entire app - $route.reload(). You can show/hide some div/directive based on manipulation in your controller.

So you have to use some form of asynchronous scripting to deal with this "PROMPT while REFRESH" situation.

Using $.ajax() to simulate (pseudo code)-

```
$.ajax({
  url: "_URL_to_get_or_post_data__",
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
    $popup.show();
  }
})
  .done(function( data ) {
      $popup.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer sir. . i dnt get what u said. but all know is impossible to do my way.

Comment: Yes, in 1 line that is not possible. But you can use Jquery Ajax to simulate if you have that kind of requirement.

Comment: so u mean. if i use jquery and ajax i can do what i want?
can u comment the code here sir..